# Unshift element on ArrayCollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have this ArrayCollection filled with a xml data coming from and HttpService request.

**The generated XML**

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Tom</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Jerry</name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>TV</name>
  </item>
</items>
```

**The script**

```
[Bindable] private var dp:ArrayCollection;

private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
    dp = event.result.items.item;
}
```

Right, this `dp` is used as a `dataProvider` in a `ComboBox`

Is there a way to add another element (at the begining) of this `ArrayCollection` ?

I tried using `unshift`, but that only worked for an `Array`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `addItemAt` method.

```
dp.addItemAt(item, 0);
```

Comment: Yes tried this way but I'm getting `[object Object]` in the ComboBox.

Comment: I did this: `var df:Array = new Array({id:'0',name:'default'}); dp.addItemAt(df,0);`

Comment: I get it now, the `item` should be an `object`. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addItemAt method, adding it at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ASDoc for the ArrayCollection class you can use the method '[addItemAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#addItemAt%28%29)'